# Cannot open database "Arriendamiento" requested by the login

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-forms

Estoy teniendo problemas para conectar una aplicación de Windows Forms a una base de datos llamada "Arriendamiento", ya he intentado muchas maneras de hacer el connection string y nunca me ha funcionado. A continuación les anexo mi código. Muchas Gracias

```
 public bool MakeConnection()
    {
        string connectionString = null;
        connectionString = "Server=DESKTOP-16G1T07;Database=Arriendamiento;Integrated Security=Yes;";
        cnn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        try
        {
            cnn.Open();
            cnn.Close();
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Pd. Creo que el problema podría estar en SQL-Server pero aún no doy con el error.

Answer (score 0):

Tuve que alterar dentro de SQL-Server el usuario que tenía para la base de datos y utilicé el sa.

```
Use Arrendamiento
GO
sp_changedbowner 'sa'
GO
```